# module 'robin_stocks' has no attribute 'get_current_positions'

Tags: python, stock

This is my first time using the robinhood api and I am trying out their documentation: https://readthedocs.org/projects/robin-stocks/downloads/pdf/latest/,
but one of their key functions is not working. When I call `robin_stocks.get_current_positions()` I get the error

`AttributeError: module 'robin_stocks' has no attribute 'get_current_positions'`

Here is my code:

```
import robin_stocks, json
from robin_stocks import *
import robin_stocks as r
import sys
import time
import requests

content = open('config.json').read()
config = json.loads(content)

login = r.login(config['username'],config['password'], store_session=True)

my_stocks = robin_stocks.build_holdings()
for key,value in my_stocks.items():
    mystocks = key,value

print(mystocks)

WEIbalance = mystocks[1]['equity']
WEI = mystocks[0]
print('YY', WEI)
positions_data = robin_stocks.get_current_positions()

print('my equity', WEIbalance)
print(positions_data)
```

Is this an error on my part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of this [commit](https://github.com/jmfernandes/robin_stocks/commit/187976bac6a1d2597b889c9bd3d4708d944e4f5d) get_current_positions was renamed to get_open_stock_positions() the corresponding issue can be found [here](https://github.com/jmfernandes/robin_stocks/pull/250)